# Python: Counting characters and displaying them in alphabetical order?

Tags: python, string, lambda, count

So I have to program something in Python that takes a string that's 20 characters or more, count how often each character comes up, and display the count in Alphabetical order with caps and lowercase letters mixed (A-a-B-b-C-c).

The phrase I'm testing is "She sells sea shells down by the seashore" which should display as:
{' ': 7, 'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 7, 'h': 4, 'l': 4, 'n': 1, 'o': 2, 'r': 1, 'S': 1, 's': 7, 't': 1, 'w': 1, 'y': 1}

However, I can't figure out how to get it to count and sort out the way I want it. Here is what I tried.

```
#This first one sorted and counted it alphabetically, however the uppercase and lowercase letters didn't stay together.

def main():
    input_str = str(input("Please enter a phrase:\n"))
    if len(input_str) < 20:
        print("Please enter a phrase that's 20 characters or more.")
    else:
        res = {}
        for keys in sorted(input_str):
            res[keys]=res.get(keys,0)+1
        print("Count of all characters in inputed phrase is:\n"+ str(res))

        
main()
Please enter a phrase:
She sells sea shells down by the seashore
Count of all characters in inputed phrase is:
{' ': 7, 'S': 1, 'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 7, 'h': 4, 'l': 4, 'n': 1, 'o': 2, 'r': 1, 's': 7, 't': 1, 'w': 1, 'y': 1}
```

```
#This second one I saw the lambda command and thought it would fix it, however it doesn't actually count the letters, it just displays them in alphabetical order

def main():
    input_str = str(input("Please enter a phrase:\n"))
    if len(input_str) < 20:
        print("Please enter a phrase that's 20 characters or more.")
    else:
        sorted_list = sorted(input_str , key = lambda s: (s.upper(),s))
        print("Count of all characters in inputed phrase is:\n", sorted_list)

        
main()
Please enter a phrase:
She sells sea shells down by the seashore
Count of all characters in inputed phrase is:
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'r', 'S', 's', 's', 's', 's', 's', 's', 's', 't', 'w', 'y']
```

How do I combine these so that it will count and sort them the way I want? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: you just need to iterate through the string and update in the dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda itself couldn't fix it, because it's not giving you the *counts*. It only helps to sort the characters in the input string.
Once you have that list of sorted characters you can use e.g. a dict comprehension to assign counts to each character and then print it:

```py
def main():
    input_str = input("Please enter a phrase:\n")
    if len(input_str) < 20:
        print("Please enter a phrase that's 20 characters or more.")
    else:
        sorted_list = sorted(input_str , key = lambda s: (s.upper(),s))
        character_counts = {item: input_str.count(item) for item in sorted_list}
        print(f"Count of all characters in inputed phrase is:\n{character_counts}")

# Input:
# oasjdoasdjoasdjasodjasopdnaosdn
# Output:
#  {'a': 6, 'd': 6, 'j': 4, 'n': 2, 'o': 6, 'p': 1, 's': 6}
```

Side notes:

- `f-string` is a newer way of formatting strings
- `input` returns a string by default, no need to explicitly cast it
- passing a `lambda` to sorting functions is just a convention and is often convenient, but it's not a "must do". You can pass any named function as well, since that key parameter is actually "how do you want me to sort the iterable"
  e.g.

```py
# Define function
def get_upper_and_non_modified_char(c: str)->Tuple[str, str]:
    return s.upper(), s
...
...
...
# Use it for sorting instead of lambda
sorted_list = sorted(input_str , key = get_upper_and_non_modified_char)
```

Comment: Ah! So you didn't want `{' ': 7, 'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 7, 'h': 4, 'l': 4, 'n': 1, 'o': 2, 'r': 1, 'S': 1, 's': 7, 't': 1, 'w': 1, 'y': 1}` after all! You wanted a single entry for `s`, the total of 1+7=`8`?

Answer (score 0):

#### Your fundamental problem is that you want the results in a non-standard order

For computers, generally alphabetical order is *usually* ABCabc, and if you don't care about capitalization, it becomes ABC (or abc). However you are doing something more subtle: retaining the case, and putting the capital of each letter before its lower case equivalent: AaBbCc.

#### I assume that you want the capital letter to always be before its corresponding lower case?

If so, you can construct a sort key composed of (say) the upper-case version of the character, after which you append an extra piece of string, that causes upper case to sort before lower case. For example, you can add a "1" for upper case and a "2" for lower case. The end-user never sees this: it is purely an intermediate step to yield your desired order.

A snippet like this would be the concept. For each key `k`, you would create a string like this which sets its sort order:

```
k.upper()+("1" if "A"<=k<="Z" else "2")
```

#### Your first program is already close

You just need it to list the keys in your desired order.

Instead of:

```
    print("Count of all characters in inputed phrase is:\n"+ str(res))
```

try something like this:

```
    print("Count of all characters in inputed phrase is:")
    
    sorted_keys = sorted(res.keys(), key=lambda k:k.upper()+("1" if "A"<=k<="Z" else "2"))
    sorted_res = { k:res[k] for k in sorted_keys }
```